# Как сократить код на Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, инспекция-кода

Есть вот такой кусочек кода, он рабочий,но некрасивый:

```py
if autorisation == "yes":
    logining()
    if not value :
        while not value :
            logining()
```

Есть ли какие то способы сократить его. Или использовать что-то другое ?
Подскажите плиз

**UPD:**
А как тогда отредактировать саму функцию ?

```py
def logining():
    login = str(input("Login: ")).lower().replace(" ","")
    password = str(input("Password: ")).lower().replace(" ","")
    loginPassword = (login+" "+password)

    open_and_close = open('data.txt')
    fromFile = open_and_close.read().splitlines()

    global value 

    for number in fromFile:
        if number == loginPassword:
            value = True
            break
        else:
            value = False   
    if value:
        print("Access allowed") 
    else:
        print("Incorrect login or password. Try again")
    open_and_close.close()
```

Comment: Как минимум можно убрать `if`. Также очень плохо, что у Вас есть глобальная переменная.

Comment: @Михаил Муругов, т.е. второй if заменить на elif или ветку else?

Comment: Второй `if` вообще убрать. Лишняя срока.

Comment: @МихаилМуругов А в чем проблема  ```global``` ?

Comment: Спасибо. А как тогда отредактировать саму функцию ?

Comment: Просто добавить `return value` последней строкой. `global value` при этом можно убрать, если значение `value` нигде больше не используется. И не публикуйте пожалуйста новый вопрос в виде ответа. Вместо этого можно отредактировать сам вопрос или задать новый

Comment: Ваш первый вызов `open_and_close()` делает именно то, что написано в названии, поэтому второй будет снова открывать и тут же закрывать. Во-вторых, не используйте алиасы на стандартные методы, типа `open()`. В-третьих, не делайте всё стразу, используйте ленивые выражения, как например чтение файла с помощью `with`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во-первых убрать

```py
if not value:
```

Эта строчка не далает ничего полезного, то же самое условие будет следом проверено в заголовке цикла

Во-вторых, можно сделать так, чтобы `logining()` возвращала `value` в случае удачи, например, добавив в нее строку

```py
return value
```

и тогда код можно будет сократить до следующего

```py
if autorisation == "yes":
    while not logining():
        pass
```

Ну и в-третьих, ваш код не станет "красивым" как минимум до тех пор, пока не перестанете использовать глобальное изменяемое состояние там, где это совсем не нужно.